# Is it beneficial to align VSTS "feature" work type to git feature branching?

Tags: git, architecture, azure-devops

We are using [git dmz flow](https://gist.github.com/djspiewak/9f2f91085607a4859a66). When feature is done it will be merge to dmz branch and be merged to master branch if it pass the CI. A feature might consist of many stories and stories may consist of many task.

Currently we consider user stories and task as "feature" in the context of git dmz flow. We branchout from master to certain stories and tasks. I feel like this is disorganize and not following feature branching and will be better to branch out from master from a feature type of work VSTS and stories and tasks under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually user story has the same function as you thought “feature” type of work in VSTS.

> User stories define the applications, requirements, and elements that
>   teams need to create. Product owners typically define and stack rank
>   user stories. The team then estimates the effort and work to deliver
>   the highest priority items.

When you checkout feature branch from `master`, you can create a series of user stories which make up the feature(s) you want to develop on this feature branch. And you can view the process of the use stories in Kanban board.

For a certain user story, you can define more detail works (tasks/bugs) in it. And you can view the work process in iterations.